# Fancybox works as page loads but not after

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have fancybox installed on my website and I am getting some strange behaviour. If i refresh the page and press a picture as the page loads fancybox will popup and work. Once the page finishes loading and then i press the picture again it says "The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later."

Why would it do that? It already let me view the picture once but after the page completely fishes loading it cannot find the picture? I can press the picture as the page is loading and then close it, then open it again without any problems. I can do that as long as that page hasnt finished loading.

**UPDATE**

This is in attachment.html:

```
<a class="various" href="#inline">
    <img src="{_file.F_FILE_THUMB_IMAGE}" alt="{_file.DOWNLOAD_NAME}" width="400px" />
</a>
<div id="inline" style="display:none;">
    <div id="mediaplayer" style="padding:10px;"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    // <![CDATA[ 
    jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({ 
        'flashplayer':'/test/player/player.swf', 
        'file':'{_file.F_FILE}', 
        'image':'{_file.F_FILE_THUMB_IMAGE}', 
        'volume':'25', 
        'provider':'video', 
        'width': '640', 
        'height': '480'     
    }); 
    // ]]> 
</script>
```

This is from the overall_header.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/test/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.0.4" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/test/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.0.4"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    // <![CDATA[ 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $(".various").fancybox({ 
            fitToView: true, 
            width: '75%', 
            height: '75%', 
            autoSize: true, 
            closeClick: false,
            closeBtn: 'true',
            scrolling: 'no', 
            padding: '5', 
        }); 
    }); 
    // ]]>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/test/player/jwplayer.js"></script>
```

Comment: First off, check the console for errors. Secondly, please post your code so we can see what's happening.

Comment: I cant really post the code, its a phpbb that is getting info from many pages.

Comment: this is in attachment.html - <a class="various" href="#inline"><img src="{_file.F_FILE_THUMB_IMAGE}" alt="{_file.DOWNLOAD_NAME}" width="400px" /></a>
<div id="inline" style="display:none;">
<div id="mediaplayer" style="padding:10px;"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({
'flashplayer':'/forums/player/player.swf',
'file':'{_file.F_FILE}',
'image':'{_file.F_FILE_THUMB_IMAGE}',
'volume':'25',
'provider':'video',
'width': '640',
'height': '480'
});
// ]]>
</script>

Comment: this is from the overall_header.html - <link rel="stylesheet" href="/test/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.0.4" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/test/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.0.4"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".various").fancybox({
fitToView: true,
width: '75%',
height: '75%',
autoSize: true,
closeClick: false,
closeBtn: 'true',
scrolling: 'no',
padding: '5',
 });
});
// ]]>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/test/player/jwplayer.js"></script>

Comment: Ok thats the stuff that does the work. I cant post all the code because the comments here only allow a small amount of characters. This all works on a mirror site with the same forum setup on the same server, why different behavior?

Comment: Ok it was what I thought might be happening, another phpBB piece of javascript code is conflicting with fancybox. I removed the javascript and everything works. Now I just need to put it back and fix it. Thanks for trying help guys. Mark this as solved.

Comment: Actually I still need a bit of help if possible, this is what is in a standard phpbb overall_header.html and is what is conflicting with the fancybox - window.onload = function()
 {
  for (var i = 0; i < onload_functions.length; i++)
  {
   eval(onload_functions[i]);
  }
 };                                                                                                                                       I'm sure that it is needed so I shouldn't delete it, but how to make this work with fancybox please? I don't really get what functions this is trying to do onload, it seems like nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to update this it was simply another script that was causing the fancybox to fail. I disabled all other scripts and it worked fine. I then enabled each script one by one to find the one causing the problems. So it's all good now, thanks for the help.